# Scrollable cell with multiple attached components in dhtmlxLayout

Tags: dhtmlx

I would like to attache to cell several Tabbars which follows one another and could be found in the cell by scrolling its content. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next way of appending different objects [like here](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxLayout/samples/05_attach_urls_and_objects/05_append_object.html). 
Where divs will be tabbars containers

And also you can use method [showInnerScroll()](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxcell_showinnerscroll.html) to force cell's scroll